# CssClass of ItemStyle does not work

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView and in the first row I want that the lines be padded on left by 20px. I tried to do it with CSSClass but does not work.

```
<div class="rounded-corners"; style=" margin-left:50px; margin-right:50px; ">  
        <asp:GridView id="MyGridView"        
         DataSourceID="MyDataSource1" 
         AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         GridLines="None"   
         AllowSorting="True" 
         AllowPaging="True" 
         CssClass="mGrid"
         PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
         AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
         Runat="Server" PageSize="35" HorizontalAlign="Justify" 
            onselectedindexchanged="MyGridView_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            onrowdatabound="MyGridView_RowDataBound">         
            <PagerSettings FirstPageText="Début" LastPageText="Fin" NextPageText="Suivant" 
                PageButtonCount="15" PreviousPageText="Précedent" />
           <columns>
              <asp:boundfield datafield="FICHIER"
                readonly="true"     
                headertext="Fichier">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="CellFile"  />
              </asp:boundfield>
              .....
              .....
              .....
```

with CssClass as below :

```
<style type="text/css">   
    .CellFile
    {
        padding-left:100px;
        margin-left:100px;  
        color:Lime;
        background-color:Red;
    }
</style>
```

So what could be wrong here ?

Comment: Define your css class like .rounded-corners .mGrid .CellFile

Comment: I even deleted all the defined classes except the .CellFile, and still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

set `ItemStyle-CssClass="CellFile"` of `asp:boundfield`

still not success, try to change you css link reference like below , add querystring at the end to load the style sheet. if css cached even you edit the css you will not see the results

```
<link href="/my.css?id=1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the whole GridView in your css just use the ID in this case `id="MyGridView`

**CSS**

```
#MyGridView{
   your stylingoptions here;
}
```

If you want to change Rows and or Collumns you can use

```
HeaderStyle-CssClass="head"  <!--For the header-->
ItemStyle-CssClass="items" <!--For the items-->
```

Ad these two to the Templatefield of your Gridview

Comment: I want only the lines of the first columns be padded not all the columns. And does not work too.

Comment: Add `ItemStyle-CssClass` to your template field of the boundfiel or whatever and set this in your css: `.items{your styling;}`